# Multiple users authenticating my app results in getting some of them suspended

Tags: ruby-on-rails, facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-authentication

I've got an authenticate app button on [my website](http://www.wavenconnect.com)

my problem I've got a booth in an event where users come to the booth authenticate my app on their account to get their account mapped to some RFID card after authenticating around 30 users in a row the user number 31/32 gets suspended 
with [a message exactly similar to this](https://www.dropbox.com/s/zblxc3hc0kz4qeu/Screenshot_2012-01-03-04-47-06.png?m)

To Reproduce :

1. Open up the website
2. Hit Connect with Facebook
3. log-out from Facebook
4. Connect using another user & so on.

Note : I'm using a Galaxy Tab & all users authenticate/login from the tablet, then logout for another user to login.

Expected Behavior :
- My App gets authenticated to user's account

What Really happens :
- The app gets authenticated like charm, but after like 30 users, one or two users gets thier accounts suspended with the above message

Comment: Could you edit this to explain the question more clearly? It might help to spell out what you would expect from an answer, and what you've already discovered in your research so far.

Comment: Are you sure this isn't Facebook's standard protection for suspicious logins? I don't think it's specific to your app, the API, or anything your app is doing?

Answer (score 0):

Check the terms and conditions of your facebook API. Could be that you are limited to 30 concurrent users and might have to pay more to get a higher number.